# docker-compose volume full due to large data, can i prevent it copying to the container but still mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very large project, it's large due to data files, i am switching to using docker as it's proving a pain for developers in different environments.

public_html/data is about 30gb in size on my local machine.

I have my docker image mapping ./ to /var/www/html which then includes the public_html folder

It can't copy the data folder to the container because there isn't enough space on the drive to have two copies of it. Is there a way that i can map the folder to the container so it can still use the folder, but have it only stored on my local machine? So in other works sort of like a sym link?

Here is my compose file

```
version: '3.4'
volumes:
  themecache:
  designercache:
services:
  utterly-web:
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public_html
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      - themecache:/var/www/html/public_html/themes/utterly/cache
      - designercache:/var/www/html/public_html/themes/utterly/designer/cache
```

Correct me please if i misunderstand, i thought everything works from the volumes on my local machine i didn't realise it actually copied the files to the container,  i now don't understand how i can edit local files and it affects the file in the container, it's already like they can as sym links?

EDIT

I realised i am copying the files in Dockerfile below, i'm going to try the .dockerignore

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite headers

COPY . /var/www/html
```

Comment: Hey, please add some syntax colouring with `\`\`\`yaml` for instance, and wrap path / filename in single backquotes: `\`/path/to/file\``. Interesting questions though...

Comment: @vinalti hi, i have updated my question i forgot about the Dockerfile where it's copying. So i'm going to try a .dockerignore

Comment: Yeah, try to avoid copying and voluming the same folder, the volume is created before the `COPY` in your dockerfile so it should not be necessary at all.

Comment: @vinalti can you see anything wrong in my config? now i get : ERROR: Service 'utterly-web' failed to build : Build failed but doesn't say why

Comment: hmm the ignore file doesn't seem to work it's still copying loads of GB

Comment: Because you're making a volume containing `.` (all your app) you can remove the `COPY . /var/www/html` from the docker file. That should work without. Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

A Linux bind mount, and by extension a Docker bind mount, does exactly what you describe: there are two different filesystem paths that point at the same underlying storage.  It is not unlike a kernel-managed symlink.

The extra copy of the data is coming from the `COPY` instruction in the Dockerfile.  Having that `COPY` instruction is generally good – you want the image to contain its own code – but you want to exclude the large data tree.

You can use a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) to tell Docker to omit files from the image (technically, the build context).  For your setup this will also make the `docker build` step go substantially faster.

```
# .dockerignore
data
```

Now you can leave the `Dockerfile` unchanged, but the final `COPY` line will include only the application code and not the data.

In your Compose setup, set up the bind mount to mount the data directory.  You frequently will not want to overwrite the image's code with a bind mount: this can hide differences between the two source trees if the Dockerfile setup does something interesting, and if you're deploying the application somewhere else, it means you need to both distribute the built application and its source.

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./data:/var/www/html/data
```